# JPA ManyToMany does not insert into join table when create

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA 2.1, mysql.

Entity Usuario

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID_USUARIO")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE", length = 30)
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "integrantes", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<NucleoFamiliar> nucleosFamiliares;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "integrantes", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<GrupoJaas> gruposJaas;

    ... getters setters
}
```

Entity GrupoJaas

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GRUPO_JAAS")
public class GrupoJaas {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID_GRUPO_JAAS")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE", length = 30)
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "INTEGRANTE_GRUPO_JAAS", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_GRUPO_JAAS") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USUARIO"))
    private List<Usuario> integrantes;

    ... getters setters
}
```

Entity NucleoFamiliar

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NUCLEO_FAMILIAR")
public class NucleoFamiliar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRE", length = 100)
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "INTEGRANTE_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USUARIO"))
    private List<Usuario> integrantes;

    ... getters setters
}
```

When I create a new "NucleoFamiliar" with a non-empty list of "integrantes", jpa executes 2 sentences as expected:

```
insert into NUCLEO_FAMILIAR
insert into INTEGRANTE_NUCLEO_FAMILIAR
```

When I create a new "Usuario" with a non-empty list of "gruposJaas", jpa executes only one sentence:

```
insert into USUARIO
```

Why is not executing insert into INTEGRANTE_GRUPO_JAAS!!???

Both codes (create "NucleoFamiliar" and create "Usuario") are almost the same, I mean, they are almost identical.

Please help, I spent days watching everything and I haven't found a solution yet (I'm using jpa 2.1)

Comment: It seems that your mapping is correct. where is the code creating and saving entities? If you post the code it might help to see why it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Usario class by using the mappedBy attribute in the @ManyToMany association mapping you have specified  owner of the two associations.

In the below two association mapping

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "integrantes", cascade =  {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<NucleoFamiliar> nucleosFamiliares;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "integrantes", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<GrupoJaas> gruposJaas;`
```

by using mappedBy attribute in the relationship you have effectively specified that the owner of these association is GrupoJass and NucleoFamiliar.

Now in a relationship the owner only can update the relationship status. Hence when you save NucleoFamiliar it also updates the relationship that is the JoinTable.

Comment: you are absolutely brilliant! thanks a lot!!! thats the answer. I have to "update" gruposJaas.integrantes in order to insert a registry in the join table! thanks again!

Comment: @Gabriel your welcome .. please also accept the answer :)